# Disqus comments are not loaded using disqus-react

Tags: reactjs, disqus, disqus-react

I have the setup like this:

```
import { DiscussionEmbed } from "disqus-react"
const DisqusComments = ({ post }) => {
  const disqusShortname = post.title
  const disqusConfig = {
    url: window.location.href,
    identifier: post._id,
    title: post.title
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <DiscussionEmbed
        shortname={disqusShortname}
        config={disqusConfig}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
export default DisqusComments;
```

Trying to embed like this:

`<DisqusComments post={item}></DisqusComments>`

Reference: https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/how-to-add-disqus-to-a-react-application

But some how the disqus plugin doesn't load at all. Could not find answers on web hence posting it here